# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop in React.js , data is not shown in table but it showing in console

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to showing the All Users List in Table using Table Row and Table body , but data is showing in console but not showing in table.

```
<TableBody>
    {
      users.map(user => (
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>{users._id}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.username}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.email}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.phone}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          ))
         }
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

React uses the key prop to create a relationship between the component and the DOM element that why it need a unique prop key for each child in list so what you should do is

```
<TableBody>
    {
      users.map(user => (
        <TableRow key={user._id}>
          <TableCell>{users._id}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.username}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.email}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{users.phone}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          ))
         }
</TableBody>
```